# In jupyter notebook the session id appearing in the url while making a call to kernal api. Its websocket call

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When Jupyter tries to re-connect with kernal the URL been sent jupyter:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://jupyter.sdp6-dev.csco.cloud/user/xyz-jupyter-user/api/kernels/ff9c5ba6-aefb-4d07-8ba8-32c6a1c1edd1/channels?session_id=118d14ea4a234b7b9a8e575f9421de24' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Don't we think this as a security vulnerability exposing the session id in the URL instead we should call API with POST verb rather a GET verb?

Comment: Websockets don’t work with POST and the verb doesn’t really change the URL. There is ongoing discussion to allow sending data in headers or some other way for this reason among browser vendors and developers.

Comment: Hi Sami thanks for quick response. Any issues raised in jupyter's github space. Please share that issue handle here. Will have a look over the discussions happened for that.